# API calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I have a `API` php functions that executes a `SQL` query from the database and encodes the values in `JSON`.

eg

```
function getApiCall(){
     $sql = 'SELECT * AS "Total" from tablename"';
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($user);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

The value on calling the URL http://localhost/getapicall/apikey in the browser is

```
{"Total":"80"}
```

In my front end HTML page using JavaScript, the API URL is called

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myJSON = $.get('../v1/getapicall/default');
document.getElementById("txt1label").innerHTML = myJSON;
</script>
```

But the value displayed is `[object object]` , how do I display the value of the json data i.e 80 in this case?

If I try putting

```
document.getElementById("txt1label").innerHTML = myJSON.Total;
```

The value gets displayed as undefined.

Comment: I mean all the other answers are probably fine, but do you dare to venture another route and use [`$.getJSON(...)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)? ;)

Comment: Esteann Afonso  check the answers below and if worked then mark that answer as accepted.Thanks

Comment: make sure to tag questions as jQuery, if you're looking for a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 1):

[`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is an asynchronous function, which means it won't return your data right away- it has to make a round trip to your server first.

Instead you pass it a function to be executed when the data is returned from your endpoint.

```
var myJSON = $.get('../v1/getapicall/default', function(result) {
    document.getElementById("txt1label").innerHTML = result.Total;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pares your json data and also wait for the get request to complete. Get being asynchronous.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$.get( '../v1/getapicall/default', function( data ) { 
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);      
    document.getElementById("txt1label").innerHTML = obj.Total;
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `$.get` returns a promise, not the actual data.